# What are the differences between a half Ghoul and a Ghoul other than having one human eye and a Ghoul eye?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

What are the differences between a half Ghoul and a Ghoul other than having one human eye and a Ghoul eye? It would seem half Ghouls have all the habilities of regular Ghouls, super strenght, regeneration, kagune, need for eating humans, etc. Are there other differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wiki article](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/One-eyed_ghoul), differences are close to minimal:

- Only one eye becomes red;
- They may have different smell than common ghouls;
- They seem to be more powerful than common ghouls, particularly increasing their power while taking damage.

No other differences were ever noted during series, and last difference was not really elaborated so far.